# Create dataservice with require.js + breeze.js

Tags: javascript, breeze, require

I'm using breeze.js to get some serverdata on the client, this works fine. To create a more modular application i want to create a 'dataservice' to bundle the breeze query's in 1 module to be included in other modules as a dependency.

this is the module:

```
define(function () {

var serviceName = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/breeze/n0uk', // route to the Web Api controller
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);


function getPoster(callsign) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Posters').where("Callsign","==",callsign);
    return manager.executeQuery(query);
};

return {
    getPoster:getPoster
};
});
```

I've created a testmodule to test the function:

```
define(["common/dataService"],function(n0uk) {
alert("home/index geladen");

n0uk.getPoster("pe1l").then(function(data) {
        alert(data.Name);
    }
);
```

});

sadly there is no data returned. I'm a breeze and require newby ( and js experience is also not topnotch). Can someone direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test module you're executing `alert(data.Name)`.  The breeze query will return an object with an array property named `results` so you probably want to use something like this:

```
define(["common/dataService"],function(n0uk) {
alert("home/index geladen");

n0uk.getPoster("pe1l")
    .then(function(data) {
        alert(data.results.length.toString() + ' items returned');
    })
    .fail(function(reason) { alert(reason); });
});
```

Other things to try:

Use your browser's F12 tools (or visual studio) to set a breakpoint and inspect the query result.

Use fiddler's "inspectors" tab to confirm your api call is returning data:
[image: screenshot of fiddler inspector]

For more info on what the `executeQuery` method returns, look here (scroll to "executeQuery"):
http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html

Comment: thanx, this was the solution!     
            alert(data.results[0].Name());
does display the correct data...